# Get search box to filter results

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, filter

I have a list of filter buttons that filter gallery items.
The filtering works well, and the filter state is saved in session storage.
I'm trying to link up the search box and button.

The behavior I'm trying to achieve is when someone types into the search box then hits enter or clicks search button, their entry is passed to the filter function and matching results are shown.

I'm having trouble getting the string and assigning it to a variable.
I'm having trouble getting the filter to work on that variable.

I made a fiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/ewebster/Lxveeq65/22/

The JS:

```
          $(document).ready(function () {


        //declare a global variable


        var filterVal;


        //check if sessionStorage exists and if so, if there is a var called fillTerm
        //if not, set it to a default value (all)
        if (sessionStorage && sessionStorage.getItem("filTerm")) {
            filterVal = sessionStorage.getItem("filTerm");
        } else {
            filterVal = "all";
            sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
        }

        //now let's attach some interaction to our buttons
        $(".filter-button").on("click", function () {
            //get the value for our filter
            filterVal = $(this).attr("data-filter");
            //store it in the session storage
            sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
            console.log(sessionStorage);
            console.log(filterVal);
            //call our view update function
            updateView();
        });

        //this is the function that manipulates the UI
        function updateView() {
            //default situation: all is visible
            if (!filterVal || filterVal === "all") {
                $('.filter').show();
            }
                //hide all and show filtered values
            else {
                $(".filter").hide();
                $('.filter').filter('.' + filterVal).show();

                console.log("searchTerm");
                console.log("filterVal");
            }
        };
        //update the view when the page loads
        updateView();

        $(".searchButton").click(function () {
        var term = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        var searchTerm = document.getElementById("searchEntry").value;

        console.log("searchTerm");
        console.log("filterTerm");
    })

    });
```

The searchButton function at the end is what is not working. I realize the button can trigger the function on click or the function can listen for a click on id of the button. In any case I haven't been able to pick up the search input.

The form may need method POST, depends where I ask.

Comment: Could you show your html as well? I'm a bit unclear on which button (the `.searchButton` or the `.filterButton`) is supposed to update the results for the user. Are they working together somehow? The html may make it clearer.

Comment: The default action for a submit button within a form is to post the form data, you need to use something to prevent the default action otherwise it will post/reload the page.

Comment: Hello, sorry that is unclear. The filterbuttons are the vertical row of text buttons that filter the items. The searchbutton is the one that says submit adjacent to the search box. The html can be seen in the upper left of the fiddle.

Comment: Hi NewToJS, thanks for that, how do I prevent the Post?

Comment: You could use `event.preventDefault();`  More information can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/jsreF/event_preventdefault.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click the button, the form is submitted and the page reloads.  There is no need to use a form if you can render it all locally.

I have updated the fiddle to remove the form, and added a new click handler.  You can add another event listener to handle the enter key and perform the same action.

I couldn't determine from your question whether you required the form to be POSTed or not.  It seemed to me that were just looking for client side, hence my answer drops the form.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lxveeq65/39/

```
        $("#searchBtn").on("click",function(){
            filterVal = $('#searchEntry').val();
            sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
            updateView();
        });

        $("#searchEntry").on("keypress",function(e){
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
              filterVal = $('#searchEntry').val();
              sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
              updateView();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, this works for me. To handle the Enter key would it look like the check if keycode ==13? $("#enterKey").keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) { send it to filter  } }); ?

Comment: @Webster yes, sorry, i've put that into the fiddle (and updated the answer). Enter key and submit button should both work now.

Comment: Thank you Tom Kay. My problem for this question is solved. What's the best way to ask for help with my next development question?

Comment: It's always best to start with a search on StackOverflow.  If you can break down your specific problem into it's smallest parts you can target the search better.  If you can't find anything from that you can post another question, which in turn may help others too :)

Comment: I haven't been able to find the answer to this or solve it myself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46533455/toggle-visibility-or-display-of-objects

Answer (score 0):

Your code is submitting the form and posting back. Change the search button to type'button' like `<button id="searchBtn" class="searchButton" type="button" >search</button>` This prevents the default type of "submit".

After that you just need to call the same code that you use for the other buttons and pull the searchterm from `$('#searchEntry').val()`.