# Toggle visibility or display of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter, visibility

I have a group of objects acted on with data filters to search and filter.
JavaScript toggles the visibility of the objects to make the searching and filtering happen.

I have some title elements that should only appear when their subject is selected. For instance if the user chooses topic #3 the results for topic #3 should be shown with the title for topic #3. If I perform a search the title should say "search results".

Where I'm lost: the gallery starts with all objects and section titles in place. The section titles should be hidden until their section topic is selected. I have class "filter" for all visible elements. If I start them out with visibility: hidden; they never show up. If I don't give them visibility: hidden; they never go away. My function is showing and hiding "all" when I need to toggle these individual elements independently of the main filtering.

Here's a fiddle showing all the titles on page load, and when you type or click "all". The only title showing in these cases should be "All results".

https://jsfiddle.net/ewebster/Lxveeq65/43/

The JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //declare a global variable
        var filterVal;
        //check if sessionStorage exists and if so, if there is a var called fillTerm
        //if not, set it to a default value (all)
        if (sessionStorage && sessionStorage.getItem("filTerm")) {
            filterVal = sessionStorage.getItem("filTerm");
        } else {
            filterVal = "all";
            sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
        }

        //now let's attach some interaction to our buttons
        $(".filter-button").on("click", function () {
            //get the value for our filter
            filterVal = $(this).attr("data-filter");
            //store it in the session storage
            sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
            console.log(sessionStorage);
            console.log(filterVal);
            //call our view update function
            updateView();
        });

        $("#searchBtn").on("click",function(){
            filterVal = $('#searchEntry').val();
            sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
            updateView();
        });

        $("#searchEntry").on("keypress",function(e){
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
              filterVal = $('#searchEntry').val();
              sessionStorage.setItem("filTerm", filterVal);
              updateView();
            }
        });

        //this is the function that manipulates the UI
        function updateView() {
            //default situation: all is visible
            if (!filterVal || filterVal === "all") {
                $('.filter').show();
            }
                //hide all and show filtered values
            else {
                $(".filter").hide();
                $('.filter').filter('.' + filterVal).show();

                console.log("searchTerm");
                console.log("filterVal");
            }
        };
        //update the view when the page loads
        updateView();

    });
```

Comment: I would suggest to not use ".hidden" css class. Instead hide all the tile in document.ready and then show them upon each button click. https://jsfiddle.net/Lxveeq65/46/

Comment: There is going to be a flicker to the end user this way.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your hard work and help. Oluwafemi Sule got me sorted out first. I promise to have more programming problems in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property rule for `display` needs to be written in `.hidden` CSS class. However, this is not enough because specificity. *You may need to wrap the titles in another div with id to get around this*.

If you're not so opposed to using `!important`, you have a solution like this.

> sessionStorage references are removed for brevity and lack of support on here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var filterVal = "all";

  $(".filter-button").on("click", function() {
    filterVal = $(this).attr("data-filter");
    updateView();
  });

  function updateView() {
    //default situation: all is visible
    $('.filter').addClass('hidden');
    $('.' + filterVal).removeClass('hidden');
  };

  updateView();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: small;
}

.item {
  height: 60px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: grey;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  overflow: wrap;
  float: left;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -35px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.filter-button {
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.filter-button:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="searchEntry" placeholder="Search">
<input type="submit" id="searchBtn" class="searchButton" />

<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="all">All </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="short">Short </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="tall">Tall </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="big">Big </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="small">Small </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="many">Many</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="filter-button" data-filter="few">Few </button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="filter all">
  All of Them
  <hr />
</div>
<div class="filter hidden short">
  Just the Short Ones
  <hr />
</div>
<div class="filter hidden tall">
  All the Tall Ones
  <hr />
</div>
<div class="filter hidden big">
  Only the Big Ones
  <hr />
</div>
<div class="filter hidden small">
  All the Small Ones
  <hr />
</div>
<div class="filter hidden many">
  The Many Ones
  <hr />
</div>
<div class="filter hidden few">
  The Few
  <hr />
</div>


<div class="filter item all big tall">
  Big and Tall
</div>
<div class="filter item all short small">
  Short and Small
</div>
<div class="filter item all big short">
  Big and Short
</div>
<div class="filter item all tall small">
  Tall and Small
</div>
<div class="filter item all big few">
  Big and Few
</div>
<div class="filter item all many small">
  Many and Small
</div>
<div class="filter item all few small">
  Few and Small
</div>
<div class="filter item all short few small">
  Short and Small and Few
</div>
<div class="filter item all big tall many">
  Big and Tall and Many
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Oluwafemi, Thanks for your answer, I see that it works, but not on my version. What did you change besides adding the hidden class?

Comment: I removed references to sessionStorage. See the fiddle here with everything still intact. https://jsfiddle.net/ewebster/Lxveeq65/43/

Comment: Aha, can it be done and still keep sessionStorage? That's an important part.

Comment: Sure. The fiddle I shared keeps `sessionStorage`.

Comment: That fiddle #43 shows all titles when I click or type "all". I'm afraid in that case it should show only the "All of them" title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155789/discussion-between-webster-and-oluwafemi-sule).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an updated fiddle with the working code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ayunami2000/4uw7or7z/

Excerpt from jsfiddle:

```
//this is the function that manipulates the UI
        function updateView() {
            //default situation: all is visible
            if (!filterVal || filterVal === "all") {
                $(".filter").show();
                $(".filter").not(".all").hide();
            }
```

Btw, I also changed `visibility:false;` to `display:none;`

Comment: HI Samual,  Thank you for the work. Your fiddle seems to do everything I'm looking for. When I put this line in my page in the place in your excerpt:  $(".filter").not(".all").hide(); none of the objects show up.

Comment: Just copy the code from the fiddle into your page, it doesn't have any extra code that you don't need in it.